# Laravel & MSSQL Stored Procedures - Returning id after insert

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, laravel

I choose to use stored procedures in my controllers when passing parameters to the database.

Example

```
$insert = DB::statement( "EXEC dbo.insertSomething ?", array( $value ) );
```

The param is passed and inserted based on my SQL code within the SP. I then try to return the SCOPE_IDENTITY() which displays fine when executing directly on the DB level. But when I try to get that same value returned via the SP back into Laravel, I simply get the resource of 1 stating the SP executed.

I also tried

```
$insert = DB::select( "EXEC dbo.insertSomething ?", array( $value ) );
```

which instead errors out and states "The active result for the query contains no fields"

Any ideas on how I can do this? I need the id of the inserted record to add desired functionality to my application.

**UPDATE TO SHOW SQL**

After the insert has taken place...

```
DECLARE @ObjectID int;
SET @ObjectID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

RETURN @ObjectID -- Doesn't work
SELECT @ObjectID AS ObjectID -- Doesn't work
```

Thanks,
DigiBathe

Comment: How is your SCOPE_IDENTITY "returned"? Using RETURN, SELECT, an OUTPUT parameter?

Comment: Hi Aaron, I tried both RETURN and SELECT, neither seemed to work.

Comment: You should be using an OUTPUT parameter. Then seek the Laravel documentation (do they have any?) to see how to retrieve output parameters after a stored procedure call.

Comment: They don't have any documentation on using SPs, just straight SQL. Thanks though.

Comment: Try `DB::select( "set noncount on EXEC dbo.insertSomething ?", array( $value ) );`